# Best way to reference a file path with Gitlab, Gradle and Bash?

Tags: gradle, gitlab

I have a bash script in my Gitlab pipeline that execute a gradle command. Within that gradle command, I reference a file. I keep getting issues with the file not being found and I assume it's because of how the relative pathing is working.

### Snippet of Gradle Command

```
            path {
                from = file("folder")
                into = '/targetFolder/'
            }
```

### Shell Script

```
  gradle :${APP_PATH}:jib
```

I've tired projectDir and I've tried relative path like `../../etc`, but no luck. What's the best way to reference the file directly? It's underneath `rootproject/config/folder`

Comment: This question is abstract, because the snippets you've added are useless; one can only assume that this might be a copy task. How about first changing the directory with `cd` before running `gradlew`? Run `pwd` to know where you are. You can go crazy with formatting as much as you'd like - but there is no content. Please provide something reproducible (such simple issue might solve itself when trying to isolate it).

Answer (score 0):

it appears that you are trying to call sub-project target when you call below in the Shell script `gradle :${APP_PATH}:jib`

as you mentioned you need config folder relative at the root-project

Use paths from rootDir of rootProject.

`files(project.rootProject.rootDir + '/config/folder')`